# Does Anyone Know The Name Of This Vocal Audio Effect?

Tags: identify-this-effect

I am learning Ableton Live and Cubase and other software. I like some effects which I listen in some songs but I don't know what to call them, and therefore, I am unable to search it on the web right now.

I got two sample video links and I hope that you could help me finding its name, and possibly link me a good tutorial about it on YouTube?

Listen to the first 20 seconds of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiSQ_db-Dcw).

And listen to the first 20 seconds of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uWGOUnwcc0).

In simple words, I am referring to this "beautifully turning voice like rhythm" and sounding very nice. The second video's first 20 seconds explain what I need very well. I mean, no one can naturally turn that way, it has something to do with effect for sure.

I thought that it's something Skrillex? But when I learnt this technique, I had to realize that I was wrong. It is something different. Not even chopping etc. It;s different.

If you know how to produce such effects, please let me know what this effect is called? And if possible, link a good YouTube tutorial for Ableton Live or Cubase.

Answer (score 4):

What you've stumbled upon is **[Auto-Tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-Tune)**. From Wikipedia:

> Auto-Tune is an audio processor created by Antares Audio Technologies which uses a proprietary device to measure and alter pitch in vocal and instrumental music recording and performances. It was originally intended to disguise or correct off-key inaccuracies, allowing vocal tracks to be perfectly tuned despite originally being slightly off-key.
>
> The processor slightly shifts pitches to the nearest true semitone (to the exact pitch of the nearest tone in traditional equal temperament). Auto-Tune can also be used as an effect to distort the human voice when pitch is raised or lowered significantly, such that the voice is heard to leap from note to note stepwise, like a synthesizer.

Auto-Tune was first used (and popularized) in the late 90s by the likes of Kid Rock on "[Only God Knows Why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DQup4hd1_o)", Cher on "[Believe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuZZqGRrSzI)", and Daft Punk on "[One More Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGBhQbmPwH8)". It has since been further popularized by artists like [T-Pain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBrRBZy8OTs), [Kanye West](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH4JPgVD2SM), and [Lil Wayne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IH8tNQAzSs), and has even spawned a web series *Auto-tune the News* (later renamed *[Songify the News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songify_the_News)*), best known for the "[Bed Intruder Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMtZfW2z9dw)".

I'm by no means a musician or producer or anything of the sorts, so I don't have an Auto-Tune tutorial to recommend, but just [searching "autotune tutorial" on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=autotune%20tutorial&page=&utm_source=opensearch) brings up a number of seemingly promising results.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks once again!

Comment: Don't forget to mark Joe's answer as the correct one if you think that it is what you were looking for!